# RFID card reader Samsung galaxy tab

Tags: android, rfid, reader

I developed an Android app for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 in Android 4.4. Now I'm trying to connect a RFID card reader through my microUSB port to emulate a keyboard so we can read different tags which contain different info. I'm using the [Syris RD200-M1-G](http://www.syris.info/reader/USB-RFID-reader/RD200-M1.html) reader. I searched a lot in the internet and I read that is compatible with Android. My problem is that I connect it to my tab and the reader is powered off and I can't do anythyng.

Do I need something to power it? or maybe in my program code? Any help will be so appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: This isn't really about programming, therefore I flagged it as off-topic.

Comment: Sorry it's the first time that I ask something in relation with this and I don't know if it's only hardware or I need to program something. I.E. in a readme file I saw that you can use it including a .dll and there is an example app that is done in visual basic. But in android we can not use .dll libraries...

Comment: I can see now why you  think that belongs here, thanks for the clarification, but I still think it's not about programming.

Comment: ok must I change my tags? or where can I post it? I never posted anything in off-topic

Comment: You misunderstand, off-topic means it doesn't belong here, it's not a separate place to post stuff. You can try posting your question on http://android.stackexchange.com/ or maybe even on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if the problem is software-related.

Comment: I looked around a bit for you and it seems your [reader gets it's power through USB](http://www.syris.info/reader/USB-RFID-reader/RD200-M1.html) and Android devices needs to support [OTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) to able to power other devices through USB. [Your tablet apparently doesn't support this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_4_7.0). So i guess that is the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin, I was reading about that and I was suspecting that was my problem